# how to reset atom state on url change?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Sidebar component which subscribes the following atom.

```
export const sidebarOpenedIdx = atom<number | null>({
  key: "sidebarOpenedIndex",
  default: 0
});
```

The sidebar has bunch of items, and one of them will be open.
if sidebarOpenedIdx === null, sidebar is closed.

What I want to do is to reset sidebarOpenedIndex on url change.

if i visit '"/products/:productId", or "products/:productId/detail',
sidebarOpenedIdx will be initialized.

I i visit url that doesn't have :productId, the atom should reset to default value.